# proftpd put: Access failed: 552 791230988: No space left on device (test.bin)

Tags: 14.04

When I upload a file, say 755M, proftpd report "No space left on device"

lftp localhost:/> put test.bin
put: Access failed: 552 791230988: No space left on device (test.bin)

but I run /bin/df -h, I can see there still are 414G avaiable.
my ftp root directory is on /home/ftproot

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      ext4      1.8T  1.3T  414G  75% /home
```

So I think there are some wrong in proftpd source code.

after I review the code, find the root cause.

proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5~rc3/modules/mod_xfer.c +2381

```
 2380     } else {
 2381         if (requested_sz > avail_sz) {
 2382         pr_log_debug(DEBUG5, "%s requested %" PR_LU " bytes, only %" PR_LU
 2383           " bytes available on '%s'", cmd->argv[0], (pr_off_t) requested_sz,
 2384           (pr_off_t) avail_sz, path);
 2385         pr_response_add_err(R_552, "%s: %s", cmd->arg, strerror(ENOSPC));
 2386         return PR_ERROR(cmd);
 2387       }
 2388     }
 2389   }
```

in line 2381, the unit requesed_sz(791,230,988) is in bytes, but the unit avail_sz(435,293,500) is in kb

see: proftpd-dfsg-1.3.5~rc3/src/fsio.c +4263

```
 4259     /* In order to return a size in KB, as get_fs_size() does, we need
 4260      * to divide by 1024.
 4261      */
 4262     *fs_size = (((off_t) fs.f_bavail * (off_t) fs.f_frsize) / 1024);
```

so to fix this bug:

```
if (requested_sz > avail_sz) {
```

have to be modify as

```
if (requested_sz > avail_sz * 1024) {
```

but I don't know how to report bug to proftpd devel team, who can commit it proftpd?

Comment: I think you should report it [here](http://bugs.proftpd.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it need create account, first.

but I don't receive any email when I submit my email(google mail),
so I can't report these bug, doesn't the maillist is ok?

Comment: reported!


http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4046